# How to delimit TextInput for timer input in React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'm working on a simple timer app right now, where a user should specify the input time as any number (screenshot included below). I want the time inputted to be delimited similar to how Google's [timer](https://www.google.ca/search?biw=1280&bih=703&ei=CvmNW8-1C9yr0PEP7I-dgAM&q=timer&oq=timer&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i67k1l4j0l6.45705.46199.0.46335.5.5.0.0.0.0.92.317.5.5.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.5.316...0i131i67k1j0i131k1.0.5tKESstHP0w) delimits the hours, minutes and seconds by small "h", "m" and "s" characters. But instead of those characters, I want to delimit using colons.

I'm currently using a TextInput as the component for inputting time. Is there any way to keep the colons "permanently", such that they appear regardless of whether or not numbers have been inputted? I was thinking of adding in the colons before I `setState`, but this would allow the colons to be able to be deleted. I was also looking into Overlay, but this might cause some spacing to look weird in between numbers and colons.

[image]